# How to identify user when server receive subscription state change notification

Tags: android, google-play

According to Android developer guide. Our server will receive Pub/Sub notification when a user buy or cancel a subscription.

But it seems we don't have any information to identify the user. How can I modify the user's data in my server accordingly?

Below is the notification I received

```
{"version":"1.0","packageName":"com.diamondtech.streammap","eventTimeMillis":"1557833856021","subscriptionNotification":{"version":"1.0","notificationType":2,"purchaseToken":"celgdoceflgifibejhfgafpd.AO-J1OxoputCKFIjQt7QgnF5hSg8jiqDCNEiBM-8kBEOTwXr4oy-33LGr8l6h2Ih1GXX7yjgcptIaatVFN5EHT4_sywD5-qruOhOJZVdwBnGM71-8N-xxxxxxxxxxx","subscriptionId":"premium"}}
```

And the response of the google verification API

```
{  "kind": "androidpublisher#subscriptionPurchase", 
"startTimeMillis": "1557832655139",  "expiryTimeMillis":
"1557834750372",  "autoRenewing": false,  "priceCurrencyCode": "TWD", 
"priceAmountMicros": "160000000",  "countryCode": "TW", 
"developerPayload": "",  "cancelReason": 1,  "orderId":
"GPA.3318-4223-0272-90442..6",  "linkedPurchaseToken":
"cjnnjplpglkmdmdhbhaecobo.AO-J1OzD_JJr1Z8pzSDvJSjujfHVp9EQUsUnBv2kf5JocYsXpT-rX954WIuOSAtmLbMzqJmHudnwvsJll1GnXThj6JoDFSAR2E01fa4eZ7lUIozMOh4a_xxxxxxxxxxxx",
"purchaseType": 0 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Very late answer but since there are no answers maybe this can help someone at least.

You only get personal information if the customer used "Subscribe with Google":
https://developers.google.com/news/subscribe/

If you have an app where the user buys a subscription, you get a receipt from Google with a purchaseToken. And since you know which user it is in the app, save the user information together with the receipt (most importantly the purchaseToken) in your database.

When you get a notification, match the purchaseToken in the notification with your database to determine which user it belongs to.

Do note that if a user cancels and then resubscribes they will get a new purchaseToken and the original one will be in the receipt from Google under "linkedPurchaseToken":
https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/purchases/subscriptions#resource

Comment: Is this still the only way to solve this? Adding an other index to the database seems to be a bit of an overkill..