# How to link user to purchase token on a google subscription renewal

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-play, in-app-purchase, google-play-billing

While using **Unity 2020.3.9f1 and Unity IAP 3.2.1** I can send the initial subscription via a regular https request to my **Spring** backend and receive the user information from backend auth + purchase token via the request. I can then insert the expiry date (which I query from **Google API** using **AndroidPublisher** and the token) to my database and give premium features to the given user for that time period.

When the subscription is about to renew, I need to update the users premium feature expiry date in the database accordingly.

I already found out, that I can receive this renewal information, even if the client is not active, via **Google Cloud Pub/Sub** by linking it with the apps monetization. The backend then receives a purchase token, but this time there is no more user information since the request was not issued through a client/server request.

I also figured out that there is/was a **developer payload** to use for that purpose. My question is how I can add this to the subscription to link renewal subscription notifications to a certain user on receiving renewal subscription notifications. I do not really want to add a new index on a (at least in test mode always unique) purchase token to my database if I do not have to.

I use **Firebase Auth** in my app - can I make use of that in any way?

Comment: Regarding https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56130192/how-to-identify-user-when-server-receive-subscription-state-change-notification storing the purchase token seems to be the only way to solve this riddle?

Comment: Maybe using a google play billing extension https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/unity is a solution which allows using SetObfuscatedAccountId() as an alternative to the obsolete developer payload. Still having problems to integrate the plugin however so I can't confirm this fix to work for now..